# Flutter BLoC - StreamSubscription not listen on dispatched event

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm using the [Flutter BLoC](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) package for manage the state of my app, but since last package update (v0.22.1) I have a strange behavior.

In simple I have a `StreamSubscription` listener on `PositionBloc`'s state in `EventsBloc` but when I add an event from `PositionBloc` the listener not work. 
The strangest thing is that the first time I add the event from `EventsBloc` the listener work, but after seems to be completely ignored.

This is my build tree:

`main.dart`: Here I show home page or the login page based on authentication. `AuthenticationBloc` and `MoviesBloc` aren't important or `LocalsBloc` the focus is on `PositionBloc`.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      builder: (context) => MoviesBloc()..add(LoadMovies()),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is Unauthenticated) {
              return Login(
                authenticationRepository: _authenticationRepository,
              );
            }
            if (state is Authenticated) {
              return MultiBlocProvider(
                providers: [
                  BlocProvider<LocalsBloc>(
                    builder: (context) => LocalsBloc()..add(LoadLocals()),
                  ),
                  BlocProvider<PositionBloc>(
                    builder: (context) => PositionBloc(
                      localsBloc: BlocProvider.of<LocalsBloc>(context),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
                child: Home(),
              );
            }
            return Splash();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`home.dart`: This is a `StatefulWidget` for manage `TabBarView` and here I provide `EventsBloc` to the widget `EventsCarousel`. In `SearchBar` widget I have the trigger for dispatch event and so rebuild the `EventsCarousel` based on selected position.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              children: <Widget>[
                BlocProvider<EventsBloc>(
                  builder: (context) => EventsBloc(),
                  child: EventsCarousel(),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: SearchBar(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            MoviesList(),
            Settings(),
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Material(
        child: TabBar(
          indicatorColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          tabs: <Tab>[
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.home
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.bullhorn,
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.cogs,
              ),
            ),
          ],
          controller: _tabController,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`search_bar.dart`: This is a `StatefulWidget` for manage `_textController` and `_focusNode`. Here I have my app state changer. I use [Flutter TypeAhead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) package for build the search bar and the entries of my search bar is provided from `LocalsBloc` that we see in main.dart. When I tap on an entry I add the event `UpdatePosition`(local) to `PositionBloc`.

```
class _SearchBarState extends State<SearchBar> {
  ...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<PositionBloc, PositionState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is PositionUpdated) {
          if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
            _textController.text = state.position.local.description;
          }

          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
            child: TypeAheadField<Local>(
                getImmediateSuggestions: true,
                textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(10.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    hintText: "Inserisci una posizione",
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  ),
                  focusNode: _focusNode,
                  controller: _textController,
                ),
                suggestionsCallback: (String pattern) {
                  return (BlocProvider.of<LocalsBloc>(context).state as LocalsLoaded)
                      .locals
                      .where(
                        (local) =>
                            local.description
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(pattern.toLowerCase()),
                      )
                      .toList();
                },
                noItemsFoundBuilder: (context) {
                  return Text('Nessun risultato trovato');
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, Local suggestion) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(suggestion.description),
                      subtitle: Text(suggestion.town),
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.gps_not_fixed),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                onSuggestionSelected: (Local suggestionSelected) {
                  BlocProvider.of<PositionBloc>(context).add(
                    UpdatePosition(suggestionSelected),
                  );
                }),
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

I have standards Bloc boilerplate for events and states and in particular for EventsBloc as I said I have this subscription:

```
EventsBloc({@required PositionBloc positionBloc})
  : assert(PositionBloc != null),
    _positionBloc = positionBloc {
positionSubscription = positionBloc.listen((state) {
  if (state is PositionUpdated) {
    add(LoadEvents(state.local));
  }
});
```

This listener not work after the first widgets tree build, but when I add event UpdatePosition from selection of an entry in the search bar the state of PositionBloc change and the event is correctly mapped to PositionUpdated. This is a very strange situation, can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that I had missed a super-call in the CTORs initializer for my `PositionUpdated` state so the listener was not invoked. This is my mistake and I had been following it for three days in debug.